# Persistent opening of Insert/edit image dialog box

Tags: tinymce-6, moxiemanager

**Issue:**
Selecting an image within tinymce active editor and clicking on another tinymce within the same page will pop up dialog box **Insert/edit image**.

**Should have been:**
Clicking on multiple tinymce while selecting an image will not trigger the pop up dialog box **Insert/edit image**.